# expected indentation error in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have this project im working on that i just started  and i tried compiling it and on line 8, no matter what I do it always has an error that says it expected an indented block and I can't find anything wrong. I've read other questions and they don't help at all. Is it a bug in compilers, or does it just not work for some reason?

```
def main():
    print("This game is the first created by the G.R.R. Digital Entertainment Division.")
    a = input("Welcome to The Forest. It is currently dawn in the middle of a temperate forest. You wake up, unknown of your surroundings. What do you do? ")
    if a == 'Go north' or 'Go North':
        print("You went North until you came to the border of the forest and a pasture. You see house with smoke coming out of the chimney ahead of you, a creek to your right, a meteor coming in from your left, and a forest behind you.")
    elif a == 'Go West' or 'Go west':
    elif a == 'Go east' or 'Go East':
    elif a == 'Go south' or 'Go South':
    elif a == 'Check supplies' or 'Check Supplies':
        print("You currently have a Compass, a dagger, a cyanide pill for suicide, a bottle of iodine, clothes, and a fannypack.")
    a =
    elif a == 'suicide' or 'Suicide':
    else:
```

The following is the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "python", line 7
      elif a == 'Go east' or 'Go East':
         ^
  IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Is that your code exactly? The 2nd print is missing the closing quote, you also don't have code to follow the `elif` statements.

Comment: Post the stack trace that tells you about the error so we can see where things went off the rails. Notice that the pretty-print of your code here on stackoverflow gives you a good hint where things go wrong because the coloring goes wrong. Consider using an editor or IDE that colorizes and gives you hints about syntax and indentation errors. They really help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot this is the unfinished unfinished product. (double unfinished is meant to be there) But the problem is only with the 'go east' elif statement, not any other one. Edited the post to include error

Answer (score 0):

Use `pass` to 'ignore' or skip a section:

```
def main():
    print("This game is the first created by the G.R.R. Digital Entertainment Division.")
    a = input("Welcome to The Forest. It is currently dawn in the middle of a temperate forest. You wake up, unknown of your surroundings. What do you do? ")
    if a == 'Go north' or 'Go North':
        print("You went North until you came to the border of the forest and a pasture. You see house with smoke coming out of the chimney ahead of you, a creek to your right, a meteor coming in from your left, and a forest behind you.")
    elif a == 'Go West' or 'Go west':
        pass
    elif a == 'Go east' or 'Go East':
        pass
    elif a == 'Go south' or 'Go South':
        pass
    elif a == 'Check supplies' or 'Check Supplies':
        print("You currently have a Compass, a dagger, a cyanide pill for suicide, a bottle of iodine, clothes, and a fannypack.")
    elif a == 'suicide' or 'Suicide':
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: use it until I fill the areas? Because I'm working now and I added a bit to the first If statement, and now the new code on line eight has the error. The problem is there is a bug on line eight no matter the code on that line.

Comment: Yep - if you have 'nothing to do' for a function / if / loop, use `pass`. It keeps python's strict indentation rules in check

Comment: The problem seems to have migrated to line 13 on some new code.  It seems to have an affinity for 'elif' statements.

Comment: just remember, if one line ends with a colon, the next line must be indented one level further. you can remove that indent when you're done with the function / loop / if

Comment: I do know that. The thing is, it's a randomly appearing problem that just migrated to line 21 even though it has a second if elif else statement inside, INDENTED

Comment: then make sure you watch 'how' you're indenting. tab != spaces. 2 spaces != 4 spaces. PEP-8 calls for all indentation to use 4 spaces, so go with that.

Comment: Im indenting in an online compiler (repl.it) and it's automatically turning it into 4 spaces each time I Tab. everything is perfectly spaced, but this one random error just pops up and won't dissapear unless I do something strange like I did to the other lines.